# Date range Bind in drop down list (when user click on command button)

Tags: asp.net

I am binding data in grdiview. Some values is From Date And End Date. and I have command button in grid view whenever user click on command button then Start Date And End Date will bind with Between dates.( Example Start Date is 5-6-2013 and End Date is 8-6-2013)
Then Date will bind like this

5-6-2013 
6-6-2013 
7-6-2013
8-6-2013

then these date will bind in drop down list.

Comment: get start date as a datetime and add days(method available for it) and store dates in any datasource(like array,list etc). After that this list bind to the dropdownlist.

Comment: show your aspx binding details